# set errormessage for customvalidator?

Tags: asp.net, validation, webforms, customvalidator

I would like to use a customvalidator control to handle all my validation, but I can't figure out how to set the error message in the code-behind for different checks. Is this possible?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can set the error message in the [OnServerValidate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.customvalidator.onservervalidate.aspx) method as you wish based on your validation logic:

```
protected void customValidator1_Validate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Value.Length < 5)
    {
        e.IsValid = true;
    }
    else
    {
        customValidator1.ErrorMessage = "Length must be less than 5.";
        e.IsValid = false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For One Control you can do like this..

```
<!-- In Designer Page  -->
<asp:CustomValidator runat="server" id="cusCustom" controltovalidate="txtCustom" 
  onservervalidate="cusCustom_ServerValidate" 
  errormessage="The text must be exactly 8 characters long!" />
<br /><br />
```

```
/* In Code Behind*/
protected void cusCustom_ServerValidate(object sender, ServerValidateEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Value.Length == 8)
        e.IsValid = true;
    else
        e.IsValid = false;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand when will the error message will show up under the textbox! anyway I want to set it when I click on the submit buton, but how ?